# Disable devise's :confirmable on-the-fly to batch-generate users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is a Ruby library that provides me with this `User` class:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_tokens
  devise :trackable, :confirmable
```

When `:confirmable` is written, a confirmation email is sent upon registration.

Last week I had to batch-create 300 users, so I commented out `:confirmable` for a few minutes before reverting.

Now I am creating a UI for user batch-creation, so I need to add/remove `:confirmable` on-the-fly. (I could also modify Devise's source code directly but I would rather not temper with it)

**QUESTION:** How to add/remove `:confirmable` on-the-fly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution by Wayne Conrad:

```
user = User.new
user.skip_confirmation!
```

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable#skip_confirmation!-instance_method